# Visual Studio Code удаленная отладка Node.JS через ssh

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, visual-studio-code, remote-access

Есть RaspberyPi для которой пишется ПО на Node.JS
На ПК под WIN я ПО уже отладил, и готовлюсь к переносу ПО на RaspberyPi.
Хочу через VSCode редактировать исходники приложения (которые будут хранится на Raspberry) и отлаживать код, чтобы в терминале VSCode видеть ошибки и смотреть вывод на console.log

К Raspberry я подключаюсь через SSH, и далее управляю через терминал в Pytty.
WinSCP установил и настроил на SUDO (могу создавать и редактировать файлы), c запуском Node.js и контролем вывода через терминал в Pytty.

В общем, есть ли возможность работать удобно и продуктивно с RaspberyPi через Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 2):

Gerasimov! Отвечаю себе, чтобы не забыть.
Пока я не научился отлаживать удалённо код на NodeJS в Visual Studio Code (VSC). Но уже научился редактировать исходники на удалённом хосте (считаем что по SSH к Малине и прочим все умеют подключаться).

1. Поставил расширение Remote FS;
2. Узнал IP адрес Малины и настроил Remote FS, для чего В VSC Файл->Параметры-> Параметры открываются настройки, в параметрах пользователя.

Заполняю:

```
"remotefs.remote": {
    "dev": {
    "scheme": "sftp", 
    "host": "192.168.43.152",
    "port": 22,
    "username": "pi",
    "password": "raspberry",
    "rootPath": "/home/pi/nodejsprojects",
    "connectTimeout": 10000
  }
}
```

`host` — адрес моей Малины. Не забывайте проверять IP малины перед подключением если адреса в Вашей сети раздаются по DHCP и менять значение host;

`rootPath` — папка с исходниками для редактирования.

- Теперь Shift+Ctrl+P вызываю Remote FS: Add Folder to Workspace. Remote FS предлагает выбрать устройство с которым требуется связаться (их может быть несколько) в моём случае это *dev 192.168.43.152:22 at /home/pi/nodejsprojects*
- Появляется папка nodejsprojects, в которую можно добавлять другие папки и файлы, так же обновлять периодически содержимое это списка файлов и папок так как автоматически он не обновляется.
- Когда редактируете файл не забывайте его сохранять CTRL+S иначе на хосте он не будет изменён.
- Проблемы (траблшутинг) Если файлы имеют владельца **root**, а вы вошли под пользователем, например, **pi** то файлы вы можете только читать и не будет возможности создавать директории. Тут рецепта два:
- войти под root
- поменять пользователя у папок/файлов на своего, это про **chown** и **How to set up super user (sudo)?** и как я это решил:
- RemoteFS can't do create/write files operations if folder was created by ROOT

pi@raspberrypi:~/nodejsprojects $ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x  7 pi **root** 4096 Jun 20 05:52 snake
The snake - folder is **ROOT**, and RemoteFS will not write changes to it.

For resolve the problem, i do:
pi@raspberrypi:~/nodejsprojects $ sudo chown pi:pi *
and test the changes

pi@raspberrypi:~/nodejsprojects $ ls -all
...
drwxr-xr-x  7 pi pi 4096 Jun 20 05:52 snake
Now, the owner of snake-folder is pi user, and RemoteFS is working to write files and create subfolders inside this (snake) folder